# How to add an aspx page to sharepoint 2007 with visual studio 2008

Tags: 2007, visual-studio, wspbuilder, aspx

Probably a question with an obvious answer, but I'm lost.
How do you add a custom aspx page (with code behind) to a project in visual studio 2008 for sharepoint 2007.

I've created the project using wspbuilder and have added a feature with receiver and other custom classes, but I find no way to add a custom aspx.net page.

Any help?

ps. once I've added it, what will be the url of it?

thanks

Edit: I've created the folder structure suggested, but I can't find a Web Form in the list of items I can add to that folder. I've created the project as a WSPBuilder project.
How can I install my missing templates

Edit2: Ok adding a new guid to the ProjectTypeGuids in the .csproj file I was able to add an aspx page at 12/template/layouts/UFeature/test.aspx

```
    <%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
    <%@ Page Language="C#"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <script runat="server">
    public static string output;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPUser user;
        output = "Ciao";
    }
    </script>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        Prova
        <%=output%>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now my problem is that it doesn't find SPUser even thought I've added the import of Microsoft.Sharepoint.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the directory structure in your solution for WSPBuilder to package & deploy it correctly.

The structure will be something like:

12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyProjectName\

Once you've got that, you can create new ASP.NET Web Forms in that folder, and they'll be deployed with the WSP.

The URL to access them will be something like

`http://myserver/sites/mywebsite/_layouts/MyProjectName/MyNewAppPage.aspx`

Comment: I can't find a Web Form in the list of items I can add to that folder

Comment: @MaurizioPz Try installing the [CKSDev extention](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) for VS, then it should appear.

Comment: @Dandroid it seems to be for visual studio 2010, I'm on VS 2008